# New hiding close-voted posts feature suggestion

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, roadmap

In the [2020 community roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/25/sharing-our-first-quarter-2020-community-roadmap/), it refers to a new feature for hiding posts that have a close vote:

> We are making fundamental changes to how our close question system works so that it’s a friendlier experience and more educational for post authors, while making it easier to edit and reopen closed questions, and reduce the burden on curators. Questions that get voted to be closed will be hidden, giving authors the opportunity to improve their questions in private.

1. Where will the question go? Will it simply be banished from the first page, or will it completely disappear?
2. Will high-rep users still be able to see hidden posts?
3. Will the question be hidden on the **first** vote, or the **last** vote?
4. Will I get a notification to improve my post if it has been hidden?

I appreciate this may not be completely set in stone yet, but it would be interesting to know the current opinions from Stackexchange on the implementation.

Comment: Hopefully the answer to all these is that they decide to _not_ hide closed questions.

Answer (score 8):

This answer is subject to change, as it was very recently discussed [on Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394871/upcoming-feature-new-question-close-experience?cb=1). Additionally, this is going to be rolled out ***on Stack Overflow only*** to begin with.

#### Where will the question go?

It'll be hidden to the main page by anyone without the close-votes privilege and isn't the original question asker. Anyone with a direct link to the question will still be able to view it. Editing is still allowed during this phase, and the system makes a point by adding another automatic "review" process to the next edit the question asker makes to their question.

#### Will high-rep users still be able to see hidden posts?

Yes, anyone with the cast close-votes privilege will still be able to see it. It's noteworthy to mention that closed questions, in the current proposal, cannot be up- or down-voted.

#### Will the question be hidden on the **first** vote, or the **last** vote?

The last vote, when the question is actually closed.

#### Will I get a notification to improve my post if it has been hidden?

You'll actually get an e-mail notification, with an edit link directly to the closed question. After you've edited the question "significantly," *(their language, not mine)* it'll be automatically reopened. Some users have [expressed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394875/11171084) their [discontent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394876/11171084) with the automatic reopen phase. I don't imagine seeing that kind of backlash go unnoticed, but I've been wrong before.

It's unclear at this time whether you can re-cast your close vote after the post has been automatically reopened, or if others have to step up to cast their own votes.

Comment: Hmm. Some users think [the first would be better](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13615/coming-soon-improvements-to-close-voting?noredirect=1#comment57621_13615).